# SQL Oracle show me value with highest ID

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I always see the last entry? IPOS = ID and this is variable.

```
select mnr, ipos 
from relac
where ipos = 1;
```

Comment: maybe with max() ??

Comment: last entry for which field?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle `12c` onward, you could use the **top-n query**:

```
select mnr, ipos
from relac
order by ipos desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Oracle`11g` and older versions , you could use `ROWNUM`:

```
select mnr, ipos
from 
(
  select * from relac
  order by ipos desc
) 
where rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation in Oracle:

```
select max(mnr) keep (dense_rank first order by ipos desc) as mnr,
       ipos 
from relac;
```

This returns the `mnr` value associated with the highest value of `ipos`, which seems to be what you are asking for.